# Is random variable X independent of Y+Z?

Tags: probability

Let the random variable $X$ be independent of the random variable $Y$ and be independent of the random variable $Z$.  Is it indeed  true that $X$ is independent of $Y+Z$ as well?

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture stated in the question is not true. A counterexample:

Define $Y$ and $Z$ as independent random variables with  $P(Y=-1)=0.5,P(Y=1)=0.5,~P(Z=-1)=0.5,P(Z=1)=0.5$.

Define $X = ZY$.

$X$ and $Y$ are independent: for $x,y,z\in\{-1,1\}$ 
$P(X = x, Y = y) = P(Y = y)P(X = x | Y = y) = 0.5 P(Z = x/y) = 0.25 = P(X = x)P(Y = y)$.

With the same reasoning, $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

However, since $Y+Z = 0$ is equivalent to $Z = -Y$, $P(X = 1 , Z + Y = 0) = 0$ , whereas $P(X=1)P(Z+Y = 0) = 0.5^2$. Hence, $X$ and $Z+Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Very clever. Thanks