# Mutual independence

Tags: probability

Supposing that $\{x,y,z \}$ are mutually independent random variables.

Can I write $\pi(x|y,z)=\pi(x)$?

Also,can I write $\pi(x|f(y,z))=\pi(x)$?

where $\pi$ denote the corresponding pdf and $f$ denoting an arbitrary function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the conditional pdf is $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
For independent $X$ and $Y$ we have $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Hence, $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{f_Y(y)}=f_X(x)$$
This also applies to any other random variable $Z=g(Y)$ that is a function of $Y$, since $Z$ is also independent of $X$. It is also  valid for three mutually independent RVs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. During my search for an answer to this, I have found this forum http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657203/is-random-variable-x-independent-of-yz
which seems to suggest that what I have written does not hold and hence contradicting your answer. Am I being mislead here?

Comment: Note that $X=ZY$ means the three random variables are not mutually independent since $X$ is completely known given $Z$ and $Y$.